# What is allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor in cassandra.yaml?

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster of 16 nodes and with num_tokens=256 with RF=3 from 3.x version. Now we are planning to migrate to v4.0.7 and I see there is a new configuration `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` with default value 3. I am not able to decide on the vluse I should configure for my cluster even after reading the document multiple times. Can someone help me to understand this and what could be the optimal value for this based on my cluster configuration

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Pokuri, I may request you to checkout out the existing articles/resources that explains the behavior in more depth and they're:

- [Community article](https://community.datastax.com/answers/5700/view.html)
- [CASSANDRA-15260](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15260)
- [Blog post on setting an even token distribution](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/21/set-up-a-cluster-with-even-token-distribution.html)

And... [Cassandra `4.1` is already generally available](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Cassandra-4.1-is-here.html) and you should consider going to that as opposed to `4.0.x` series to leverage the benefits.

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the `cassandra` tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: that thelastpickle article and community articl helped me

Answer (score 3):

To be concise, it's better to keep num_tokens lower because it adds overhead to certain operations like repair for example.  So, if you decide to use vnodes, choose something like 8, then set allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor to 3 if you plan to use an RF of 3 for the user-created keyspaces and you'll still get acceptably even data distribution without the need to set a high number of vnodes.

Comment: its a cluster running since 2017 with 256 tokens, now can we adjust those tokens to 8? what would be the process? As per documentation, it was mentions node wont start if th num_tokens wont match with what other nodes have in cluster

Comment: That's correct @Pokuri. You cannot change the tokens on the existing datacenter (DC) of the cluster. When you add a new DC, you could set the desired tokens values there on the nodes within that DC and add it to the cluster. Each DC will have a homogeneous configuration across all nodes within it. As Paul said, I'd start with `8` for `num_tokens`, RF & `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` of `3` on the non-system keyspaces.

Answer (score 1):

### Background

By default, random tokens are generated and assigned to a new node added to a cluster when virtual nodes is enabled (`num_tokens` in `cassandra.yaml`). Since the allocated tokens are random values, there is a slight skew in the load (amount of data) between nodes.

The skew is more pronounced when the number of tokens (vnodes) is small such as 8 or 16 compared to 256 vnodes. To deal with this skew, **new token allocation algorithms** have been introduced in more recent versions of Cassandra.

### Cassandra 3.x

In Cassandra 3.0, a new allocation algorithm was introduced which tries to pick tokens which provides an even distribution of ownership (data load) across the cluster based on the replication strategy of a keyspace ([CASSANDRA-7032](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7032)).

To trigger this algorithm, specify the keyspace to be optimised for in `cassandra.yaml` with:

```
allocate_tokens_for_keyspace: keyspace_name
```

If not set, tokens will be picked at random as normal.

If you are interested in the details, [see the `ReplicationAwareTokenAllocator.java` class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.6/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/dht/tokenallocator/ReplicationAwareTokenAllocator.java). Note that this algorithm is only supported with the `Murmur3Partitioner`.

### Cassandra 4.x

The `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace` property suffers from the problem where the replication factor of a keyspace cannot be used when adding a new DC since the keyspace is not *yet *replicated to the new DC.

The new allocation algorithm in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-15260](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15260)) was built on top of `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace` but solves the problem by allowing cluster administrators to specify the replication factor of the most used keyspace.

To trigger this algorithm, specify a replication factor in `cassandra.yaml` with:

```
allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor: 3
```

You would typically set it to the replication factor of the largest application keyspace in your cluster. If not set, tokens will be picked at random as normal.

If you are interested in the details, [see the `TokenAllocation.java` class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0-alpha4/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/dht/tokenallocator/TokenAllocation.java). Note that this algorithm is only supported with the `Murmur3Partitioner`. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!